# What is the ansible equivalent to find -exec cp with file extensions filtered?

Tags: shell, automation, ansible, devops

I need to replace this kind of command:

```
- name: Copy files .par
  shell: find {{ path_src }}/* -name '*.ext' -exec cp {} {{ path_dest }} \; | find {{ path_src }}/ -type f -a ! -name "*.*" -exec cp {} {{ part_dest }} \;
  ignore_errors: yes
```

The '*.ext' can be different on the same task and it's linked to the destination if i find '*.sql' i want it to go to the destination .sql

I try this kind of solution

```
- name: TEST COPY
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Test Find
      find:
        paths: /home/me/test/find_cpy
        file_type: file
        recurse: yes
        patterns: ['*.ext','*.sql','*.sh']
      register: find_list

    - name:
      debug: var=find_list

    - name: test set fact
      set_fact:
        path_file: "{{ find_list.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
      register: test_fact

    - debug: var=test_fact

    - name: test sql copy
      copy:
        src: "{{ test_fact.path}}"
        dest: "/home/me/test/test_copy/sql"
        owner: me
        mode: 0755
        when: ????

    - name: test register
      copy:
        src: "{{ item.path }}"
        dest: "/home/me/test/test_copy/"
        owner: me
        mode: 0755
      with_items: "{{ find_list.files }}"
```

The test register is ok but the test sql copy i have no idea.
Any Ideas

Thanks

Comment: Why are you piping two `find`s together, when the first one doesn't emit stdout the second one reads? That's generally the only situation when a pipeline is ever appropriate. Using it in other situations can have unwanted side effects, like exit status being ignored and earlier pipeline components being forced to exit early if later ones finish before them.

Comment: BTW, if you're on a GNU platform, it's a lot more efficient to use `-exec cp -t {{path_dest}} {} +` -- using the `+` instead of the `\;` means that `find` puts as many filenames as possible onto each `cp` command, and using `-t` means that the destination directory is the one with the name immediately after the `-t`, instead of being the last one in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only few changes are needed

```
- name: TEST COPY
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Test Find
      find:
        paths: /home/me/test/find_cpy
        file_type: file
        recurse: yes
        patterns: ['*.ext','*.sql','*.sh']
      register: find_list

     - name:
       debug: var=find_list

    - name: test set fact
      set_fact:
        path_file: "{{ find_list.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
#     register: test_fact
```

Registered variable `test_fact` is not needed. The list of the paths has been stored in `path_file`.

```
    - debug: var=path_file

    - name: test sql copy
      copy:
#       src: "{{ test_fact.path}}"
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: "/home/me/test/test_copy/sql"
        owner: me
        mode: 0755
      loop: "{{ path_file }}"
```

Loop the list of paths `path_file` and copy items to the destination.

```
    - name: test register
      copy:
#       src: "{{ item.path }}"
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: "/home/me/test/test_copy/"
        owner: me
        mode: 0755
#     with_items: "{{ find_list.files }}"
      loop: "{{ path_file }}"
```

Loop `find_list.files` and `item.path` gives the same results as `path_file` and `item`. I'm not sure what the purpose of this task should be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Welcome to SO! See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).